# In Photoshop, is there a way to bring things in front or send to back?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I'm a newbie in Photoshop so I am unsure if you can brings layers to front or send to back?

I'm trying to draw a line but it goes hidden on an existing layer. How do I bring that line to front?

Comment: This depends a bit on your situation, but layers panel (F7) could be something to take care of that. Object that is higher in the layers panel will be in front of object that is lower in the layers panel. Or maybe you are trying to do this inside one vector mask, that can't be done. There is no arranging in photoshop like illustrator has. Layers are used for that.

Comment: Yes, are you drawing vector shapes or using regular pixel-based brush tools?

Comment: Joonas comment is the most helpful thing on this page, most of the answers are actually less helpful than the comment. @Joonas you probably should make that comment an answer I didn't upvote any answers they were all pretty bad, your comment was actually helpful! Have an upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the Layers, the highter -> more on top ( front )

Get the Layers windows from View/Windows.

Answer (score 4):

`Command-]` and `Command-[` (Mac) / `Ctrl-]` and `Ctrl-[` (Win) will move a layer up and down in the layers panel.

Add shift...
`Command-Shift-]` and `Command-Shift-[` (Mac) / `Ctrl-Shift-]` and `Ctrl-Shift-[` (Win) and the layer will jump to the top or bottom of the layer stack.

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple in PS CC. All you do is grab the layer you want to move, click and hold with your mouse, and drag it where you want it. It will automatically drop behind the layer that you place it under in the panel on the lower left.